# How to measure Qml Application startup time? / boot duration?

Tags: javascript, performance, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I designed different circular gauge with qml canvas and I am trying to measure their performance with QML Profiler. I also need to observe the application's boot time and reduce it.

How can I measure application start time with QML Profiler? Or are there any other tools related to this?

Comment: Look [here](https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/slides/Day2/ThomasMcGuire_Analyzing%20Performance%20of%20Qt%20Quick%20Applications.pdf) for some tips.

Comment: thanx @daljit97, this your found answer my problem